# Android: Multiple APKs for different versions of OpenGL ES

Tags: android, apk, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0, android-multiple-apk

I'm making a game in Unity for mobile.. The artist really really wants to use Linear colour-space instead of gamma colour-space.. Linear colorspace requires openGL ES 3.
The problem is that [21% of Android devices only support openGL ES 2.](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/)

So I could make two APKs, one with *only* openGL ES 3 support and linear colour-space, and one with openGL ES 2 support and gamma color-space.

But, [apparently on the google play store OpenGL ES version is not something you can filter for..](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks?hl=bn)

Any ideas what I can do?
Thanks!

Comment: It is possible to support both OpenGLES3 and OpenGLES2 in the same executable (essentially, you try to create the GLES3 context, and if it fails, you create a GLES2 context). However, I don't know how well that approach maps to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, ETC2 support came with OpenGL ES 3.0 so I believe that can be used as a filter instead.

Quoting from this page: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/texture

> Note that it’s generally a good idea for one of your APKs to support
>   ETC1, as that texture format is supported by all Android-powered
>   devices that support the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec.

*I am also considering doing the same thing as you do. Switch to linear but still make a gamma version for 2.0 devices and upload as a multi-apk. 
Please (somehow) keep me updated if it works out.*